# How to specify the container of a PrincipalContext in a format of a tree structure instead of the current weird format?

Tags: c#, active-directory

Instead of this weird format:

```
OU=HU,OU=EMEA,OU=securityGroups,OU=usersAndGroups,DC=corporate,DC=mycompany,DC=com
```

I want to specify it like this:

```
corporate.mycompany.com/usersAndGroups/securityGroups/EMEA/HU
```

Here is my code that is working with the weird format but not with the format that I want:

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null, paramPath))
{
    using (var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, paramGroup))
    {
        var users = group.GetMembers(false);
    }
}
```

Or can I convert one path format to another? Besides "DC=corporate,DC=mycompany,DC=com" all the other path elements can be only OU?

Comment: This *weird* format is the **standard LDAP** format for addressing objects in LDAP - the "distinguised name". So if you do any work with LDAP / Active Directory, you better get used to it soon ! ..... As far as I know, there's no way around using the *weird* format - learn it, or leave it

Comment: Well, nothing is stopping you from converting the string
    `"corporate.mycompany.com/usersAndGroups/securityGroups/EMEA/HU"`
into 
`"OU=HU,OU=EMEA,OU=securityGroups,OU=usersAndGroups,DC=corporate,DC=mycompany,DC=com"`
yourself...

And for the record, I totally agree, it's a **_wierd_** format ;)